# Let $−2000 < m < 0$ be a squarefree integer, $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ has class number one. Then $m\in \{−1, −2, −3, −7, −11, −19, −43, −67, −163\}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

It is also in the Exercise 10 in chapter 5 of Marcus Number Fields.

Let $−2000 < m < 0$ be a squarefree integer, $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ has class number one. Then $m\in  \{−1, −2, −3, −7, −11, −19, −43, −67, −163\}$

My strategy to find non principal ideals for each $m$ which is not in the list. Also I can use prime integers which can build any squarefree number between $-2000<-<0$, then I can look at their over primes $p\mathcal O_K$ in over. And maybe I can use the idea of norm. However I cannot connect these machineries.

Comment: Wikipedia (German) uses the class number formula for the example -163, and Wikipedia (English) has better context and explanations.

Comment: If $m\not\equiv 1\bmod 4$ then $(2)$ isn't inert, for $2$ to be a norm it must be that $m\ge -3$. Then for $m\equiv 1\bmod 4$ check if each odd prime up to the Minkowski bound and for which $m$ is a square $\bmod p$ is the norm of some element of $O_K$?

Comment: Would you accept a solution using computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the program suggested by reuns’s argument:

Let $m$ be such a discriminant and assume that $m \neq 1 \pmod{4}$. Then the ring of integers of $K$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$, so $K$ is ramified at $2$. If $K$ has class number one, the ideal $I$ whose square is two is principal of generator $\alpha$, and the norm of $\alpha$ is then a positive integer with absolute value $2$, so $2$ is a norm. Thus $x^2-my^2=2$ has a solution. As $m <0$, this implies $m \in \{-1,-2\}$.

We’re going to do this again with other primes. So now we always assume that $m=1\pmod{4}$, ie $m=1-4A$, so that the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ with $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{m}}{2}$.

Assume that $p$ is a prime dividing $m$, so $p>2$ is coprime to $A$ and $4A-1=Bp$: then $K$ is ramified at $p$, and the generator $\alpha$ of the ideal whose square $(p)$ has, as above, norm $p$. But write $\alpha=x+y\omega$, then the norm of $\alpha$ is $x^2+xy+Ay^2=p$. This can be re-written as $(x+y/2)^2+\frac{(4A-1)}{4}y^2=p$. So if $B>4$, then $\frac{(4A-1)y^2}{4} > py^2 \geq p$, hence a contradiction. As $B$ is odd, $B$ is one or three.

But by doing the same reasoning with $3|m$ (if $B=3$), we see that $p = 3$, so $m=-9 \neq 1\pmod{4}$. Therefore $m=-p$, with $p = 3\pmod{4}$ prime.

We can assume $p \geq 23$. Then, if $q<p/4$ is an odd prime, $q$ splits in $K$ iff $-p$ is a square mod $q$. But if $q$ splits in $K$, then, as above, $q$ must be a norm, ie we must have integer solutions to $(x+y/2)^2+py^2/4=q$. As $q < p$, we must have $y=0$, so $q=x^2$, which is absurd.

So $-p$ is never a square modulo any odd prime smaller than $p/4$. In particular, we must have $p=1\pmod{3}$ (so $p=7\pmod{12}$, disqualifying $23$, so we assume $p\geq 31$), $p=2,3\pmod{5}$ (disqualifying $31$, so we can assume $p> 43$), $p=1,2,4\pmod{7}$.

As $p\geq 43$ is congruent to $7$ mod $12$, if $p \leq 163$, then $p \in \{55,67,79,91,103,115,127,139,151,163\}$. Of them, we rule out $55,91,115$ for being non-prime, $67,163$ for being in the problem statement, $79,139,151$ by the criterion mod $5$, and only $127$ remains.

We rule out $127$ by the criterion mod $11$ – as $-127$ is a square mod $11$.

Anyway, the four congruence conditions above make for six congruence classes mod $420$, so at most $30$ integers less than $2000$.

We compute that these congruence classes are $43,67,127,163,247,403$, so we get the integers $247,403$ and everyone plus $420$, plus $840$, plus $1260$, plus $1680$.

Let’s add a few more criteria, with $q=11,13,17$: $p=1,3,4,5,9\pmod{11}$, $p=2,5,6,7,8,11\pmod{13}$.

By the mod $11$ criterion, we see that only remain $43+420k$ ($1 \leq k \leq 3$), $67+420k$ ($1 \leq k \leq 4$), $127+420k$ ($k=3,4$), $163+3 \cdot 420$, $247+k\cdot 420$ ($k=0,2$), $403+k\cdot 420$ ($k=1,4$).

Combining with a look mod $13$, only the integers $43+k\cdot 420$ ($k=1,2,3$), $67+4\cdot 420$, $247+2\cdot 420$ remain.

Now, we compute (by hand!) that $-463, -883, -1087,-1747$ are squares mod $17$, while $-1303$ is a square mod $23$, which rules them out.